# Bitbake build error, Patch does not apply bitbake error?

Tags: patch, yocto, bitbake

I created new question, because I felt the previous one had been answered and this belongs in a new place.

I run `bitbake core-image-minimal` and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: systemd-1_232-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_232-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch 0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch
patching file units/systemd-udevd.service.in
Hunk #1 FAILED at 21.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file units/systemd-udevd.service.in
Patch 0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: systemd-1_232-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_232-r0/temp/log.do_patch.5314
ERROR: Task (/home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_232.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
```

I located the place where the patch is written in file `meta-toradex/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend` :

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/systemd:"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://rndis.network \
    file://0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch \
"

PACKAGECONFIG_append = " networkd"

do_install_append() {
    # The network files need to be in /usr/lib/systemd, not ${systemd_unitdir}...
    install -d ${D}${prefix}/lib/systemd/network/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/rndis.network ${D}${prefix}/lib/systemd/network/
}

FILES_${PN} += " \
    ${nonarch_base_libdir}/systemd/network \
```

I was told that I can :

1. Remove the patch.
2. Apply it manually.

To remove the path, Should I just remove it from `SRC_URI` list?
How does one apply patch manually? I tried to google this, I did not quite get how this can be done.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking at [repo manifest](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/toradex-bsp-platform.git/tree/default.xml?h=LinuxImageV2.8-next), `meta-toradex` is not used, and in [meta-toradex](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/meta-toradex.git/), it says `oe-core BSP layer (obsolete)`. I think you're not using the right environment.

Nevertheless, if you want to check patch problem, you can use `devshell` with `bitbake -c devshell systemd`, then type `quilt push` in new console. You then need to analyze with patch fails to apply by looking at patch file and corresponding source code.

You should not modify existing layer, and create your own layer overriding recipes, but if you want to, you can indeed remove patch to SRC_URI, then use `bitbake -c clean systemd; bitbake systemd` and it should be OK.

In Toradex developer [knowledge-base](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-(core)#V21_and_Later_Images), if you are making a new environment, i think you need to look at `V2.1 and Later Images` section.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to not using the right environment? I am using poky on pyro branch on Ubuntu 14.04. I just cloned pyro added some layers.

Comment: Additonally i tried setting up the way you mentioned,everything works fine, I need to add a layer that requires all other layers to be on pyro branch, I check and the layers here dont seems to be on any branch?

Comment: The fact that the setup works even without the layer meta-mender-core on pyro branch makes me want to cry... Ive been struggling with this for days

Comment: I tried to add meta-virtualization layer in the pyro branch and it works, I tried to add meta-mender in the same pyro branch and it gives me funny errors. Which branch should I have my layers on for this setup?

Comment: if you join #yocto on [freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/), it can be easier to explain. When you say `I need to add a layer that requires all other layers to be on pyro branch`, what layer are you talking about? You can change manifest.xml file of git google repo to have specific version/branch of a specific layer.

Comment: meta-mender-core is a layer I need to add. It expects all other layers to be on pyro. I was intitally using poky and it was on pyro branch, everything was working. But then I added meta-openembedded layers and something happened. So i created a new setup and it works untill I add meta-mender-core.

Comment: I get an open ssl error with the basic setup, me doing the steps mentioned on the site, its got nothing to do with the layers im adding, any toughts?

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815494/bitbake-error-openembedded-core-meta-recipes-connectivity-openssl-openssl-1-0-2j

Comment: additonallly linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5 do_fetch (pid 22181)  26% |#####################  is always stuck at 26% even when rerun.wheras my other setup works fine?

Comment: you can clone repository in download folder without bitbake and add a .done file. You can also [tweak git configuration](http://www.strichnet.com/tuning-git-for-large-binary-repositories/)

Comment: I still get a Task (/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.17.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1', without any added layers....

Comment: about cloning the repo manually, how do I clone exactly linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5 from git://git.toradex.com/linux-toradex.git? I can find a branch for linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x but not the 2.7.5?