# Bitbake error openembedded-core/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.2j.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

UPDATE: bitbake core-image-minimal without any added layers gives me errors such as:

```
ERROR: Task (/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.17.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

I just initlized the repo like here https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-(core)#V21_and_Later_Images

and made no changes whatsoever! Image 2.8 is giving me problems with a layers that requires things to be in the same branch.

UPDATE: Adding full manifest for morty and rocko

rocko

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/Angstrom-distribution" name="githa"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/Freescale" name="githf"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/OSSystems" name="githo"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/meta-qt5" name="githq"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/morphis" name="giths"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/watatuki" name="githt"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/openembedded" name="oe"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://git.toradex.com" name="tdx"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="https://git.yoctoproject.org/git" name="yocto"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="https://github.com/mendersoftware" name="mender"/>

  <default sync-j="4"/>

  <project name="bitbake.git" path="layers/openembedded-core/bitbake" remote="oe" revision="1.36"/>
  <project name="meta-angstrom.git" path="layers/meta-angstrom" remote="githa" revision="angstrom-v2017.12-rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-browser.git" path="layers/meta-browser" remote="githo" revision="master"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale-3rdparty.git" path="layers/meta-freescale-3rdparty" remote="githf" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale-distro.git" path="layers/meta-freescale-distro" remote="githf" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale.git" path="layers/meta-freescale" remote="githf" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-jetson-tk1.git" path="layers/meta-jetson-tk1" remote="githt" revision="Morty"/>
  <project name="meta-lxde.git" path="layers/meta-lxde" remote="tdx" revision="rocko-next"/>
  <project name="meta-openembedded.git" path="layers/meta-openembedded" remote="oe" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-qt4" path="layers/meta-qt4" remote="yocto" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-qt5.git" path="layers/meta-qt5" remote="githq" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-snappy.git" path="layers/meta-snappy" remote="giths" revision="pyro"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-bsp-common.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-bsp-common" remote="tdx" revision="rocko-next"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-demos.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-demos" remote="tdx" revision="rocko-next">
    <copyfile dest="export" src="buildconf/export"/>
  </project>
  <project name="meta-toradex-nxp.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-nxp" remote="tdx" revision="rocko-next"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-tegra.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-tegra" remote="tdx" revision="rocko-next"/>
  <project name="openembedded-core.git" path="layers/openembedded-core" remote="oe" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-virtualization.git" path="layers/meta-virtualization" remote="yocto" revision="rocko"/>
  <project name="meta-mender.git" path="layers/meta-mender" remote="mender" revision="pyro"/>
</manifest>
```

morty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/Angstrom-distribution" name="githa"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/Freescale" name="githf"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/OSSystems" name="githo"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/meta-qt5" name="githq"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/morphis" name="giths"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/watatuki" name="githt"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://git.linaro.org/git-ro/openembedded" name="linaro"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://github.com/openembedded" name="oe"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="http://git.toradex.com" name="tdx"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="https://git.yoctoproject.org/git" name="yocto"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="https://github.com/mendersoftware" name="mender"/>
  <remote alias="repo" fetch="https://github.com/mem" name="mem"/>

  <default sync-j="4"/>

  <project name="bitbake.git" path="layers/openembedded-core/bitbake" remote="oe" revision="991b533f1d61042a7b3edd1fbf3dea0bf9991606" upstream="1.32"/>
  <project name="meta-angstrom.git" path="layers/meta-angstrom" remote="githa" revision="9625910bb4bb48b3f4d87a1e9ff3576d40bd656a" upstream="angstrom-v2016.12-yocto2.2"/>
  <project name="meta-browser.git" path="layers/meta-browser" remote="githo" revision="1569eeb9cc1b87632abbf35fbb05f4ac4eeb3987" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale-3rdparty.git" path="layers/meta-freescale-3rdparty" remote="githf" revision="e55167c3c2770c07a475342f99cc2a3a23fbfa0c" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale-distro.git" path="layers/meta-freescale-distro" remote="githf" revision="cd5c7a2539f40004f74126e9fdf08254fd9a6390" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-freescale.git" path="layers/meta-freescale" remote="githf" revision="05681fdf8298bb441c15135eae424c7601b07e98" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-jetson-tk1.git" path="layers/meta-jetson-tk1" remote="githt" revision="e8b87fe8da7c6fcffa37ab245f50082953cc1ee1" upstream="Morty"/>
  <project name="meta-linaro.git" path="layers/meta-linaro" remote="linaro" revision="5d2cb685217794293ea2bab18d7e62019c329d06" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-lxde.git" path="layers/meta-lxde" remote="tdx" revision="1bd36a4d0f7e1e9fdea9c4c991188bc1dc9da421" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-openembedded.git" path="layers/meta-openembedded" remote="oe" revision="b40116cf457b88a2db14b86fda9627fb34d56ae6" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-qt4" path="layers/meta-qt4" remote="yocto" revision="f389368dc86e745df14cab9eeb9a94bc02bd273e" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-qt5.git" path="layers/meta-qt5" remote="githq" revision="2c9f0e4eb0e9097f6f872ec1e1d81768a8ab5f1b" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-snappy.git" path="layers/meta-snappy" remote="giths" revision="f6df6a63756d9976bcccb5fefdbc64e5cc794c99" upstream="master"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-bsp-common.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-bsp-common" remote="tdx" revision="bb3fafea5a3094909c8d7fb3216c37210fcfc339" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-demos.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-demos" remote="tdx" revision="a08f1a3164e9ce16fca09f1f1c016b81eb1fcfaa" upstream="morty">
    <copyfile dest="export" src="buildconf/export"/>
  </project>
  <project name="meta-toradex-nxp.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-nxp" remote="tdx" revision="c4f34b34bf34f44b974a7add623cafff17d880ad" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-toradex-tegra.git" path="layers/meta-toradex-tegra" remote="tdx" revision="8deaad62384fbe4f4079f62bb7fdfa70ef199236" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="openembedded-core.git" path="layers/openembedded-core" remote="oe" revision="93b7f83a4212409a55ddf568a34468d4f6ef2c06" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-virtualization.git" path="layers/meta-virtualization" remote="yocto" revision="morty" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-mender.git" path="layers/meta-mender" remote="mender" revision="morty" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="oe-meta-go.git" path="layers/oe-meta-go" remote="mem" revision="master" />
</manifest>
```

Not sure how to add the revisions? I know the branch name should be in upstream but without revision it doesnt let my do repo sync

UPDATE: I update the environment as you suggested, and this is what i got while showing layers:

```
WARNING: No recipes available for:
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-freescale/dynamic-layers/browser-layer/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-wayland_48.0.2548.0.bbappend
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-freescale/dynamic-layers/browser-layer/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_52.0.2743.76.bbappend
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-jetson-tk1/recipes-graphics/mesa/mesa_11.1.1.bbappend
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-toradex-demos/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx_0.12.%.bbappend
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-toradex-demos/recipes-support/icu/icu_57%.bbappend
  /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-toradex-demos/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_2.4.bbappend
```

and also gives me error while bitbaking and gets stuck here:

```
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build'
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.23443)
ERROR: Task (/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.18.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
Waiting for 1 running tasks to finish:
0: binutils-cross-arm-2.29-r0 do_fetch (pid 10996)  35% |##############################
```

is this normal?

I have a setup from here https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-(core)#V21_and_Later_Images with all my layers in morty branch like the following:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "apalis-imx6"
DISTRO            = "angstrom"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "v2016.12"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon       callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta-angstrom     = "HEAD:9625910bb4bb48b3f4d87a1e9ff3576d40bd656a"
meta-toradex-nxp  = "HEAD:c4f34b34bf34f44b974a7add623cafff17d880ad"
meta-freescale    = "HEAD:05681fdf8298bb441c15135eae424c7601b07e98"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:e55167c3c2770c07a475342f99cc2a3a23fbfa0c"
meta-toradex-tegra = "HEAD:8deaad62384fbe4f4079f62bb7fdfa70ef199236"
meta-jetson-tk1   = "HEAD:e8b87fe8da7c6fcffa37ab245f50082953cc1ee1"
meta-toradex-bsp-common = "HEAD:bb3fafea5a3094909c8d7fb3216c37210fcfc339"
meta-snappy       = "HEAD:f6df6a63756d9976bcccb5fefdbc64e5cc794c99"
meta-linaro-toolchain = "HEAD:5d2cb685217794293ea2bab18d7e62019c329d06"
meta-oe           
meta-efl          
meta-gpe          
meta-gnome        
meta-xfce         
meta-initramfs    
meta-systemd      
meta-networking   
meta-multimedia   
meta-python       = "HEAD:b40116cf457b88a2db14b86fda9627fb34d56ae6"
meta-lxde         = "HEAD:1bd36a4d0f7e1e9fdea9c4c991188bc1dc9da421"
meta-browser      = "HEAD:1569eeb9cc1b87632abbf35fbb05f4ac4eeb3987"
meta-qt4          = "HEAD:f389368dc86e745df14cab9eeb9a94bc02bd273e"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:2c9f0e4eb0e9097f6f872ec1e1d81768a8ab5f1b"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:cd5c7a2539f40004f74126e9fdf08254fd9a6390"
meta-toradex-demos = "HEAD:a08f1a3164e9ce16fca09f1f1c016b81eb1fcfaa"
meta              = "HEAD:93b7f83a4212409a55ddf568a34468d4f6ef2c06"
meta-virtualization = "morty:eb6b5129561eda9ea1f47e85ab9ed9e5a6b8f64c"
```

But when bitbaking I get the following error?

```
ERROR: openssl-native-1.0.2j-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: openssl-native-1.0.2j-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15463)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15463
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8 -e MAKEFLAGS= depend
| making depend in crypto...
| make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/openssl-1.0.2j/crypto'
| makedepend: warning:  cryptlib.c (reading /usr/include/stdlib.h, line 32): cannot find include file "stddef.h"
|   not in ./stddef.h
|   not in ../stddef.h
|   not in ../include/stddef.h
|   not in /usr/include/stddef.h
| makedepend: warning:  cryptlib.c (reading /usr/include/sys/types.h, line 146): cannot find include file "stddef.h"
|   not in ./stddef.h
|   not in ../stddef.h
|   not in ../include/stddef.h
|   not in /usr/include/stddef.h
```

and this :

```
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/openssl-1.0.2j'
| make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/openssl-1.0.2j/crypto'
| make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/1.0.2j-r0/temp/log.do_compile.5421)
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/rama/repositories/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.2j.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: you should try rocko branch by initializing `repo init -b LinuxImageV2.8-next`, creating a new BSP with old morty branch is not so wise.

Comment: got it will try this, how do I update the repo and keep the changes I made?

Comment: Make a copy of .repo/manifest.xml, then replace it by this [file](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/toradex-bsp-platform.git/plain/default.xml?h=LinuxImageV2.8-next), and merge back your modifications. You then need to `repo sync` without doing `repo init`.

Comment: updated question

Comment: it also seems to get stuck here Waiting for 1 running tasks to finish:
0: binutils-cross-arm-2.29-r0 do_fetch (pid 10996)  35% |##############################                                                        | 1.41 MiB/s

Comment: Adding my repo to the manifest asks for a revision parameter, how do I get the correct revision?

Comment: I now have this <project name="meta-virtualization.git" path="layers/meta-virtualization" remote="yocto" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="meta-mender.git" path="layers/meta-mender" remote="mender" upstream="morty"/>
  <project name="oe-meta-go.git" path="layers/oe-meta-go" remote="mem" upstream="master"/> but its wrong

Comment: please post your full manifest

Comment: done. im also having the problem that meta-mender is not available on the rocko branch, so I think I should revert to morty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161304/discussion-between-nayfe-and-meek).

Answer (score 2):

maybe you do not have installed all the required programs for building, I have a similar situation and I just install qemu, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and gcc-none-linux-gnueabi.